# Format DateField model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I used DateTime Field to format the date, but doesn't seem to work, what could be the isssue, below is my code :

```
from django.conf.locale.de import formats as de_formats
    
de_formats.DATE_FORMAT = 'd.m.Y'
```

This is the model :

```
 contract_signed_on = models.DateField(
        _('Contract signed on'), null=True, blank=True)
```

I want the date format to be like this :
`04.3.2022`

but it's not showing the exact format

Answer (score 1):

Add `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in your settings.

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    "%d.%m.%Y",
]
```

Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Comment: How to handle this with different language switching, for may case I use English and German

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris I think you can set `USE_L10N` to `True` in your setting to enable local format. see doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_L10N)

Comment: Thanks , though what I mean in English I may like a different format like `"%d-%m-%Y"`, then in German `"%d.%m.%Y"` , is this possible with your answer